# What would be good log parser GUI tool?

Tags: logs, web-server, log-analysis

**Looking for a good GUI log parsing tool which have the following abilities**

- Can read logs from remote server [via network share, ftp or other
  protocols]
- Can read logs from imported log files from other servers

*note: trying to avoid any type of installation on the remote servers of any kind*

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about pricing? What OS(es) do you need it to run on?

Comment: Thanks for your response,Os have to be on Windows, Prefer free but if there is a really good one will do all this then will consider paid version. I liked the way Log parser lizard works but were not able to do those requirements at least with free edition

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash), an open source server-side data processing pipeline that can transport and process your logs, events, or other data. Logstash is known for its extensibility, as there are hundreds of plugins for it.

Check out the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/logstash).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html), an advanced analysis monitoring software. Can be used as a tool for collecting, monitoring, visualizing and analyzing machine data from any source. It's a commercial one, but the trial version if free of use and got no many limitations.

You can use huge amount of log files from different sources, which get indexed, so you can query the data.

Checkout the [Splunk questions at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splunk) to look for any feature you need.