# Structured Log viewer

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, log-analysis

Is there a log viewer

- for [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) 16.04
- which is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)

Preferably in the Ubuntu repositories or available via PyPI/pip, but if the quality is really high having it only on Github should be ok as well.

At a minimum, the log viewer should have the following properties / features:

- Remove the JSON syntax and display the logs in a nice way
- Automatically update when the file is updated
- Be able to handle big log files (10 MB should not be a problem, it would be nice if it could deal with 100 MB easily as well)

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/logfile` works good for me, sometimes I add a `|grep servicename` - ie, `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep named`

Comment: @ivanivan Well... if you use this, you don't benefit from structured logs, do you?

Comment: If you "remove" JSON (what logs have JSON inside, by the way?) you don't benefit from their structure either, do you? :) But yes, concerning `tail` I'm with you in this context. I sometimes use the "System Logs" tool that ships with the desktop (I'm using Mint Cinnamon) for structured view – and tail/less as well, depending on what I'm doing. *System Logs* should almost meet your requirements (not sure about the JSON part, though).

Comment: @Izzy I wrote "remove JSON syntax", meaning that it should not simply display it. I am new to structured logging and currently I don't know how it is better than usual logging, so I can't really tell which features a log viewer should have.

Comment: @Izzy I had a short look at `Log Viewer 1.12.0` (MATE), but I don't like it. I can't see how this log viewer is better from `tail -f` / using sublime text.

Comment: Ah, looks like I misunderstood something: you're speaking of log files entirely made up of JSON – and by "remove JSON syntax" you rather meant *interpreting its structure* and formatting the results accordingly (so e.g. `["foo":"bar", "bug":"buck"]` would result in two columns (foo, bug) with the corresponding values (bar, buck) being shown)? Maybe you wish to link to e.g. [this article](https://stackify.com/what-is-structured-logging-and-why-developers-need-it/) I just found and point out what you mean/want based on examples from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Log Viewer alternative for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/apache-log-viewer-alternative-for-linux)